# Rollup: (define|require|module) is not defined

Tags: javascript, gulp, rollupjs

I'm trying to use [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) with [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/)

The following is my Gulpfile:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const rollup = require("rollup-stream");
const vue = require("rollup-plugin-vue");
const resolve = require("rollup-plugin-node-resolve");
const commonjs = require("rollup-plugin-commonjs");
const json = require("rollup-plugin-json");
const babel = require("rollup-plugin-babel");
const globals = require("rollup-plugin-node-globals");
const source = require("vinyl-source-stream");
const buffer = require("vinyl-buffer");
const uglify = require("gulp-uglify");

// ... CSS tasks and the like

gulp.task("js", function scriptTask()
{
    rollup({
        input: "js/app.js",
        plugins: [
            vue(),
            resolve({
                jsnext: true,
                browser: true
            }),
            json(),
            commonjs(),
            babel({
                exclude: ["node_modules/**"],
                presets: [["env", {modules: false}]],
                plugins: ["external-helpers"]
            }),
            globals()
        ],
        format: "iife",
    })
        .pipe(source("bundle.js"))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("../dist"));
});

// ... default tasks and the like
```

This seems to successfully pull all dependencies and performs tree shaking, but then the output file doesn't run. Depending on the value of the "format" option passed to Rollup, I get one of the following errors when trying:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at bundle.js:1
    at bundle.js:1
    at bundle.js:1

Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at bundle.js:1
    at bundle.js:1
    at bundle.js:1

Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at bundle.js:1
    at bundle.js:1
    at bundle.js:1
```

**Nothing works!**

Comment: I think i solved your require module look at my answer

Comment: Im still trying to solve your other 2 errors

Answer (score -1):

You should attach this to the end of your script.

```
gulp.task('default', ['js']);
gulp.task('build', ['js']);
```

Comment: The issue is not one of running the script. The issue is that after running the script the output is incorrect